# T/F: Every bounded infinite closed set contains a rational number.

Tags: real-analysis

I think the answer to this is True. Can I show this by using Bolzano-Weierstrauss to find a limit point, and then in some $\epsilon$-neighborhood would be a rational $r$?

Comment: You've formulated a good starting idea! Here's a counterargument though: why would the $\epsilon$-neighborhood (and hence $r$) be contained in the closed set?

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider that the limit point could at the end of the set, which would imply the $\epsilon$-neighborhood being outside of the set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

False: consider $\{\sqrt 2 \}\cup\{\sqrt 2+1/n:n\in \Bbb N\}$